# In memory MySQL table vs Redis, about insert and concurrency performance

Tags: mysql, redis, in-memory-database

Since data is stored in memory in both cases, is it possible to have the same approximative insert/s and concurrency performance for both?

If not, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Concurrency for the MySQL `MEMORY` storage engine is not good. Like MyISAM, it can only do table-locks. So all concurrent threads doing inserts queue up against each other.

Comment: Isn't that what Stack Overflow is for? To solve programming problems?

Comment: So offer up a Tool Rec for him Bill

Comment: @Drew What he really wants is 50K writes a second and someone to solve it for him , yes this is what i want , in sql world if possible

Comment: @Bill oh table lock sounds not good .. any way to have  50K writes a second in sql world on a non farm server ?

Comment: Yes, 50K inserts per second is not hard if you have a good server. Here's a blog post from 2011 where the author achieved 275K inserts/sec in MySQL, and was thinking of strategies to raise that to 400K or 500K. https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/01/07/high-rate-insertion-with-mysql-and-innodb/ If you have a problem achieving 50K in 2016 then you probably have an underpowered server or you haven't learned how to tune a database.